# Remove temporal files after send email spool with Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have two form in my app. One of them for send an issue and other for send CV. Both have attachments like images or pdfs. After submit the form, an email is sent to the admin site with the attachment **without storing the file in database**. I store the file in a temporal path and after send the email, I use unlink php method to remove the temporal file. This works fine when I send the email at the moment.

Now, I'm using file spooling and a cron job to run the command **php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send** for send the emails. The problem is here. I can't do the unlink of the file path because it will be send when the cron job executes the command but I need to remove this file after send the email.

How I can track this files for when the spool has been send the command remove the files? I read about using events in console: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/events.html Even if this was useful for me, I can't use it because the Symfony version I'm using is 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending emails by running command `php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send`, you could then create a command `php app/console swiftmailer:spool:clear` to unlink all your files and run this command just after `swiftmailer:spool:send`.

Comment: Yes but how I pass the references of files I want to unlink?

Comment: If you're sending all your emails, you can unlink all your files. There's still an edge case where a file is created between two commands, so you may remove files older than x minutes.